# How to assign values to an array using method call

Tags: java

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to assign values to an array.

The size of the stringName array is determined through user input (the getNumberofStrings method). I'd like the user to enter values for the stringName array through JOptionPane. I've written a method (getStringName), but can't figure out how to call it from the main method. Any advice for this beginner is much appreciated.

```
public class NoClassp3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numberOfStrings = getNumberOfStrings();
    String[] stringName = new String[numberOfStrings];
}   // end method main

public static int getNumberOfStrings() {
   String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of strings in integer format");
   int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
   return number;
}   // end method getNumberOfStrings

public static String getStringName(String[] name) {
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter string name");
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
        name[i] = input;
    return input;
}   // end method getStringName
}   // end class NoClassp3
```

Comment: You never call `getStringName` method.

Comment: can you debug to see if the main method is called? maybe you have another main method in other class?

Comment: I apologize if I didn't make it clear, but I'm trying to figure out how to call the getStringName method. The code above is the only class that I have and only code that I have written so far for my assignment.

Comment: good question +1, maybe [this example](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#ai) would help you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
public class NoClassp3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numberOfStrings = getNumberOfStrings();
    String[] stringName = new String[numberOfStrings];
    stringName = getStringName(stringName);

    for (int i = 0; i < stringName.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(stringName[i]);
    }
}   // end method main

public static int getNumberOfStrings() {
   String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of strings in integer format");
   int number = Integer.parseInt(input);
   return number;
}   // end method getNumberOfStrings

public static String[] getStringName(String[] name) {
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
        name[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter string name");
    return name;
}   // end method getStringName
}   // end class NoClassp3
```